# GPU not available in docker

Tags: linux, docker, cuda, centos, gpu

I am unable to run GPU on Docker after updating the GPU driver.
When I run `nvidia-smi` in the host environment (Centos), the GPU is recognized.

`docker run --gpus all -it -v $(pwd):/home/workspace test /bin/bash`

```
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled 
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver &quot;&quot; with capabilities: [[gpu]].
```

From what I have researched, it seems that updating the GPU driver removes the settings, so I referred to [NVIDIA container toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html) site and performed the installation procedure again, but the above error is still there. I also rebooted the system just to be sure, but this did not solve the problem.
What should I do?

`docker run -it --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi`
This also generated the above error as well.

Answer (score 3):

What made the difference for me was to follow the instructions from Docker on [how to access an nvidia gpu](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#access-an-nvidia-gpu)

> 1. Follow [the instructions](https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/) to add `nvidia-container-runtime` to `apt`
> 2. apt-get install nvidia-container-runtime
> 3. Ensure the `nvidia-container-runtime-hook` is accessible from $PATH: `which nvidia-container-runtime-hook`
> 4. Reboot

Comment: the only person on the internet to give the best answer...this made my day!

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you followd well installation procedure:

Now, from Tutorial: how to attach NVIDIA GPU with docker
https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-use-an-nvidia-gpu-with-docker-containers/

Use the nvidia base image instead of your image `test`

```bash
docker run -it --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi /bin/bash
```

If it's not running well, your image `test` needs further debugging

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
`docker run -it --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi`
I ran it, but got an error.
`docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled `

Comment: `docker run -it --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi /bin/bash`
too

Comment: I'd advise to re-do your installation and check your GPU is well available

@hohohohoho